# How to check a JSON Array contains different/multiple key - value pairs

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON Array and want to realize a filter engine and i try do find a solution to get all these entries with a special key:value pair and push it into a sep array.

The JSON looks like this:

```
var sample = {
    "response": {
        "things": [{
            "index": 0,
            "type": 1,
            "img":2
        },{
            "index": 1,
            "type": 0,
            "img":1
        },{
            "index": 2,
            "type": 1,
            "img":1
        }]
    }
};
```

Example HTML:

```
<select name="type">
<option value="0">one</option>
<option value="1">two</option>
...
</select>
```

currently i have made a well running solution to filter only with one key and value, that is not the point. The problem is to take the object: Object:{param:1,param:2,param:3,param:n} and find all entries with exactly these filter pairs.

i doesnt found a correct way to handle it with multiple or how to use here, so i hope someone can help please.

```
        var uri =['http://example.com?type=1&img=0'];

        for (var i = 0, len = uri.length; i < len; i++) {
            var result = this.qwertzSplit(uri[i]);
        }
        testing(result);
//qwertzSplit contains the Object: Object{type="1",img="0"}
    function testing(result){
        var obj = this.sample,indexes = [];

        for (result in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(result)) {
                indexes.push(result);
            }
        }
       console.log(indexes);
}
```

So in my case the solution from kolink and my current doenst work as well as i need it. And i also cant find correct way with JS to solve it. My question here isnt duplicate because the posted links handle the single way, not a multiple way.

So i must find a way to get all entries with the given key/value pairs which take out the URI

Comment: I'm sure you'll manage to do it if you read the links on the right.

Comment: I don't understand your question...give an example.

Comment: That is not JSON. JSON is a ***string*** representing an object.

Comment: @Kolink +1 [**There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"**](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Comment: @Kolink: technically it's text on SO, so it could be considered JSON under certain light :) .... though, even that text is interspersed with HTML, so you win

Answer (score 0):

> my question is how get all entries with the type:0 and save this information into a Javascript array – JohnDoo 1 min ago

That's easy.

```
var out = [], i, l = sample.response.things.length;
for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
    if( sample.response.things[i].type == 0) out.push(sample.response.things[i]);
}
```

Comment: An iterator. It is set to each of the keys in... wait, I misread your pooly-formatted code. Give me a minute to edit.

Comment: Your code isn't formatted very well either, Kolink. From a professional point of view it's impressive, but it does little to nothing to help the OP understand and solve his problem...

Comment: @kolink, it works, but if i try to insert the params and not a direct input of .type === 0 it doent work. the parameters exists so i see it by .log. here is my code:         testFunctionw:function(key,value){
             var obj = sample.response.things;

             var out = [], i, l = obj.length;
             for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
                 if( obj[i].key == value) out.push(obj[i]);
             }
             console.log(out);
        }

Comment: sry guys i cant format my code or add a new answer to my question... but in my case of code the console.log is ever empty. if i inser the key as a existing child in JSON like "type" etc it works. whats wrong?

Comment: So just replace `.type` with `[key]`

Comment: thanks a lot kolink it works :) solved!

Comment: That's trivial. Just use a basic `&&` operator.

Comment: hmm no idea anyone? need help please